# Set different colors for each column in DotNet.HighCharts

Tags: javascript, .net, highcharts, dotnethighcharts

Is there a way to implement a chart having each column in different color using DotNet.HighCharts?

Answer (score 2):

The attributes for a single point (in your case a single column) can be set individually from the entire series.
See: [Highcharts API point -- color](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#point--color).
And this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/point/color/) for example.